# How do I fetch the post id's for Wordpress posts using their Rest API with SwiftUI

Tags: wordpress, swiftui, wordpress-rest-api, swiftui-foreach

I'm trying to include some blog posts from my WordPress site into my app. I've tested the API using the individual post Ids for each post and I got it to load the data in my view. However, I'm now trying to fetch an array but it doesn't seem to be fetching the IDs related to the posts to populate the view. What am I doing wrong here?

```
   let content: MarkdownData
@State var beholdarticles: BeholdArticle?
@State private var htmlContent = ""





let articles: [BeholdArticle] = []



private func loadArticle() {
    
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://behold.hagleyparksda.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts") else {
        return
        
    }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {data, response, error in
        
        guard let data = data else { return }
        if let decodedData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(BeholdArticle.self, from: data){
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.beholdarticles = decodedData
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

This is the ForEach loop

```
var body: some View {
    
    ScrollView (.horizontal) {
       
           
      
        ForEach(articles) { item in
            ZStack {
                     
                        if beholdarticles?.thumbnail != nil {
                            
                            WebImage(url: URL(string: beholdarticles!.thumbnail)!)
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                .frame(width:350, height: 450)
                            
                        } else {
                            
                            Image("behold_imagecard")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        }
                        
                        
                        HStack {
                            VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                                Text(beholdarticles?.title.rendered ?? "Loading...")
                                        .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold))
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                    .frame(width: 270)
    //                            Text(beholdarticles?.title.rendered ?? "Loading...")
    //                                    .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .regular))
    //                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    //                                .frame(width: 270)
                            }
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        
                            
                         
                        VStack {
                            Spacer()
                            HStack {
                                Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "healthicon"))
                                Text("Spirituality")
                                    .font(.system(size: 23))
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            .background(VisualEffectBlurView(blurStyle: .systemUltraThinMaterial))
                        }.onAppear{
                            loadArticle()
                        }
                    
                   
            } .frame(width:350, height: 450)
            .shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.2549019754, green: 0.2745098174, blue: 0.3019607961, alpha: 1)) .opacity(0.2), radius: 20, x: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/0.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, y:14)
            .cornerRadius(30)
        }
        
      
        }
```

My data model

```
struct BeholdArticle: Decodable, Identifiable  {

var id: Int
var slug: String
var link: String
var thumbnail: String
var title: BeholdArticleTitle
var content: BeholdArticleContent

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

    case thumbnail = "jetpack_featured_media_url"
    case slug, link, title, content
    case id = "id"
}
}

struct BeholdArticleTitle: Decodable {

var rendered: String
 }

struct BeholdArticleContent: Decodable {

var rendered: String
}
```

I'm simply trying to populate my loop with the data, but it doesnt seem to be grabbing the ID's from api call. Need some help here

I still have the image URL wrapped in a conditional statement. At current the images wont come through. How do I adjust this to the updated setup?

```
  if beholdarticles?.thumbnail != nil {
                                
                                WebImage(url: URL(string: item.thumbnail)!)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                    .frame(width:350, height: 450)
                                
                            } else {
                                
                                Image("behold_imagecard")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            }
```

Here's the updated image code:

```
ForEach(articles) { article in
                ZStack {
                         
                            if article.thumbnail != nil {
                                
                                WebImage(url: URL(string: article.thumbnail)!)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                    .frame(width:350, height: 450)
                                
                            } else {

                                Image("behold_imagecard")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to decode the JSON from that URL endpoint, you're going to need to use `[BeholdArticle].self` instead of `BeholdArticle.self`, since it's an array of data.

Also, instead of calling `loadArticle` on each element of the `ForEach` (which will never get called, since it doesn't have data in it at the beginning), call it at the top level of the view.

Here's a pared down example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var articles : [BeholdArticle] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(articles) { article in
                    Text(article.title.rendered)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    if let thumbnailURL = URL(string: article.thumbnail) {
                       WebImage(url: thumbnailURL)
                           .resizable()
                           .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                           .frame(width:350, height: 450)
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            loadArticles()
        }
    }
    
    private func loadArticles() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://behold.hagleyparksda.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts") else {
            return
        }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {data, response, error in
            
            guard let data = data else { return }
            if let decodedData = try? JSONDecoder().decode([BeholdArticle].self, from: data){
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.articles = decodedData
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped a lot, thank you, I totally forgot to switch the data to an array. I only have one more issue, which is getting the thumbnail image to come in. The titles will load fine but the images won't load

Comment: @KevonBrown sounds like that might be better in the focus of another question. I'm not sure what `WebImage` is (it's not a default part of SwiftUI) or how it loads images. Also, make sure you're not using two different arrays -- in your example, you have both `articles` and `beholdarticles`

Comment: Oh ok, I understand. Its actually a dependecy from SDWebImage that I imported

Comment: The more I look at it, the more I think it's because you're doing `if beholdarticles?.thumbnail != nil`, which doesn't make sense -- just use `article` from the `ForEach` closure like in my example.

Comment: I changed it, and i'm still getting a preview crash. Once I kept it in the if statement Xcode tells me that "Comparing non-optional value of type 'String' to 'nil' always returns true" When I remove it from the if statement the preview crashes (i'm assuming because of the force unwrap)

Comment: So I removed the WebImage modifier and used Swift's default Image modifier. I'm not getting any more preview crashes, however all the data loads but the image comes up blank. I've updated my question with the latest code to show you.

Comment: In the latest update I see, you're still using `beholdarticles?.thumbnail`, which doesn't make sense.  Look at the update to my answer for how I would approach it. And, you can't use the default SwiftUI `Image` with a web-based image like this. So, you're right to be using a package like `SDWebImage`

Comment: Sorry, the beholdarticles?.thumbnail was before you had posted, I had since changed it to reflect what you showed me. I'm gonna update the question with what I have now

Comment: Did you read my last comment about not being able to use `Image` with a web-based image like this? Or check my updated answer?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your updated answer. Will try that

Comment: It worked!, but now for some reason the image has covered all the text in the ZStack, I'm looking further to see if something moved in the code

Comment: Okay -- glad it worked. Please consider upvoting the answer as well, if it was helpful to you.

Comment: Yeah it seems there was a type error somewhere. Everything is working perfectly. You are a Jedi! Thank you so much